# C# MVC Rotativa ViewAsPdf System.Exception: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)

Tags: c#, pdf, model-view-controller, rotativa

I am currently trying to implement a PDF Generator for a view using Rotativa(Installed the NuGet Package, C# MVC). But when I trigger the PDF Generation I get the following error message:

```
System.Exception: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
```

My Code: In the controller:

```
  public ActionResult DownloadViewPDF(int Id)
    {
        var model = new Registration();
        model = db.Registrierungen.Find(Id);

       return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("DownloadViewPDF", model) { FileName = "Course.pdf" };

    }
```

The view:

```
    model Plattform.Models.Registration

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Teilnahmebestätigung";
}

<h2>GeneratePDF</h2>
Hiermit bestätigen wir, dass @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Nutzer.Vorname) @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Nutzer.Nachname) erfolgreich an folgendem Kurs erfolgreich teilgenommen hat
<p>
    Kurs : @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Kurs.Titel)
</p>
<div>
    <h3> Informationen zum Teilnehmer:</h3>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Nutzer.Vorname)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Nutzer.Vorname)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Nutzer.Nachname)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Nutzer.Nachname)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Nutzer.Heimatuni)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Nutzer.Heimatuni)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Nutzer.Email)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Nutzer.Email)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Registrationsdatum)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Registrationsdatum)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Informationen zum Kurs</h3>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Kurs.Titel)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Kurs.Titel)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Kurs.Termin)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Kurs.Termin)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Kurs.Ortsangabe)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Kurs.Ortsangabe)
        </dd>

        <h4> Informationen zum Organisator des Kurses</h4>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Kurs.Organisator.Nachname)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Kurs.Organisator.Nachname)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Kurs.Organisator.Vorname)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Kurs.Organisator.Vorname)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

So what is causing this Qfont error? What is Qfont? can I set it somewhere so this error does not happen?

Comment: Possibly something to do with your CSS? Try generating with any CSS and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved it.

- Download **0.12.4** from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html
- Install on your **local machine** Copy `wkhtmltopdf.exe` from C:\Program
  Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin to solutio\Rotativa
- Build and Run the application